# How to update an npm dependency from a github repo with a new tag?

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I have a node js project that uses some github repos as dependencies. For example, the `package.json` contains:

```json
"dependencies": {
   "some-lib": "github:some-org/some-lib#v1.0.0"
}
```

The `#v1.0.0` is pointing to a specific tag (a release), and I want to switch to another release, e.g., `v2.0.0`.

If I update the `package.json` line to...

```json
"dependencies": {
   "some-lib": "github:some-org/some-lib#v2.0.0"
}
```

...and then run `npm i`, lo and behold nothing happens (which I expected). So I delete `package-lock.json` and do `npm i` and the library still does not get updated. I was under the impression that `npm install` used the `package-lock` file first, then `package.json` second.

Finally I do `rm node_modules`, delete `package-lock.json` and do `npm i`; the package is updated. What is a better way to do this? FWIW - I'm also maintaining the github repo that I'm using, so can make changes there.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-install/ covers all your options pretty well? (is it a short read? no. Is it a _complete_ read? yes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [npm package.json docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#git-urls-as-dependencies) you can try adding `semver` to the dependency URL.

That might give npm more information so it updates the module when you change the dependency version number in your `package.json`.

```
"dependencies": {
   "some-lib": "github:some-org/some-lib#semver:v2.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1727

It may be that you need to `rm -rf node_modules/your-module` as well as dropping the package lock, then try `npm install` to resolve this

Comment: I mention that in the desciption, but specifically ask if there is a better way than doing that.